# How do I remove the "Request New Password" link?

Tags: users, 6

When I visit www.example.com/user, there is a page that shows the login/password and as well as a "Request New Password" tab.

How do I remove this "Request New Password" tab from the user page?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just hide that tab or disable the functionality it provides?

Comment: Disable and hide both ways would be appreciated. I'll make the choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [No Request New Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass) module is probably the easiest way to go, though you'll need to dig for the 6.x [releases](https://www.drupal.org/project/noreqnewpass/releases). This disables any request to `user/password`, so this path with neither be accessible directly nor display in menus/tabs/links.

Alternatively, you can put its main function into your own custom module:

```
 /**
  * Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
  */

 function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$callback) {  
     $callback['user/password'] = array('access arguments' => array(FALSE));
 }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, the code you gave above, where exactly in template.php should I place the code? Thanks again!

Comment: Support for alter hooks in template.php was added in Drupal 7, for Drupal 6 you'll need to put this in a custom module @user3236765

Comment: Thanks Clive, can the module referred to above work with drupal 6?

Comment: @Clive Thanks, it's been a while since I dealt with D6.

Comment: Me too, I had to check ;) @user3236765 yes that module should work out of the box. Nitpicking - the code in Jaypan's answer is a slightly better solution than what that module does, it will potentially save database access and some cpu cycles, plus it's conceptually the "better" way to solve the problem. It's technically possible for the implementation of `user_access` to change and that method to stop working, or at least start throwing warnings, but it's very unlikely given D6 isn't being actively developed

Answer (score 1):

You can change the permission so the page is not accessible:

```
function hook_menu_alter(&$menu)
{
  $menu['user/password']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

This code will disable the page altogether, so it's not available to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using a custom module (called, for example, *custom_module*) you can hide the user/password tab using the following code.

```
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/password']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

This doesn't show the tab, but the path is still accessible to the users who know Drupal has that path.

To hide it and disable it, use the following code.

```
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/password']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Setting the access callback to `FALSE`, the tab will not be accessible nor visible to any user, including the user #1.

In the last hook implementation that I shown, using `$items['user/password'] = array('access arguments' => array(FALSE));` is wrong since:

- Setting the access arguments to an array containing the `FALSE` value is **not** the correct way to avoid Drupal checks the user has the permission to see the route/menu.
- Using that code, I am literally setting the route definition to an array containing just `'access arguments' => array(FALSE)` with all the consequences that could happen if there is another module that re-enables the user/password tab for the currently logged-in user, and that module has hooks invoked after the hooks of your module. (With the example code I shown, this simply happens when the other module is called *destiny_change_user_password_tab*.)